# Как заблокировать Memo?

Tags: delphi

Прошу прощения, возможно тупой вопрос, но как написать в Memo что-нибудь (не режиме работы программы), а написанное заблокировать?

И если не затруднит, расшифруйте

```
if (not fileexists('testf.txt')) or (not fileexists('otvf.txt')) then begin
  showmessage('123');
  close;
end;
```

Comment: > расшифруйте //if (not fileexists('testf.txt')) or (not fileexists('otvf.txt')) then begin // showmessage('123'); // close; // end;

Окно закроется если хотя бы один из файлов `testf.txt'` или `otvf.txt` не существует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В run-time:

```
  memo1.Text := 'Hello world!';
  memo1.Enabled := false;
```

В design-time: воспользуйтесь свойствами `Lines`,`Enabled` и `Read-only`.